# Export to Excel issue with numbers converting as text in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a price column in tablix with currency format("$"). when i export the report to excel this column is converting to text. Could anyone let me know how to make it as number in excel.

Comment: Are you using C2 for format in the properties of the textbox?

Comment: No. I am using the expression "FormatCurrency(Fields!Cost.Value,2)"

Answer (score 0):

As TPhe mentioned, you can use the **Format** property to format the text box with **C2** for currency (**C** for Currency and **2** for the number of digits after the decimal). Using the Format property **usually** makes Excel format the cell correctly.